# SQL externalisation for Node JS (XML parsing)

Tags: javascript, xml, node.js, parsing

Assume I have the following file:

```
<sql-requests>
  <sql-request id="insert_product"><![CDATA[INSERT INTO products]]></sql-request>
  <sql-request id="insert_account"><![CDATA[INSERT INTO accounts]]></sql-request>
  <sql-request id="insert_news"><![CDATA[INSERT INTO news]]></sql-request>
</sql-requests>
```

I want to parse this xml in node and then access CDATA like this:

```
var sql = parsedXml.insert_product; // must return 'INSERT INTO products
```

What would be the best approach to this? Which package according to my preference should I use? I could not find a package which could read CDATA values.

**Answer** (Many thanks to Felix for giving the idea on how to do this)

```
var parseString = require('xml2js').parseString;
var fs = require('fs');
var content = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/sql-requests.xml');

var sql = {};

parseString(content, function (err, result) {

var queries = result['sql-requests']['sql-request'];

queries.forEach(function(query){
    var id = query.$.id, request = query._.trim();
    sql[id] = request;
});

});
```

Now, `sql["insert_product"]` will return `INSERT INTO products`

Comment: *"I could not find a package which could read CDATA values."* That's hard to imagine. Any XML parser should be able to handle CDATA sections. Which one did you try?

Comment: I have tried xml2js, libxmljs. I can write CDATA with these but could not find a way to read CDATA.

Comment: xml2js works fine for me. Changing the [example](https://github.com/Leonidas-from-XIV/node-xml2js#shoot-and-forget-usage) to `var xml = "<root><![CDATA[Hello xml2js!]]></root>";` works just like expected.

Comment: Changing the xml to `<roots><root id="sd"><![CDATA[Hello xml2js!]]></root></roots>` will output: `{ roots: { root: [ [Object] ] } }` . Hello xml2js won't be displayed, unless id is removed.

Comment: That's just the representation in the console because the ID adds additional nesting to the data structure. Do `console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));` to see the complete structure.

Comment: Thank you Felix. I do get the following output: {
  `"roots": {
    "root": [
      {
        "_": "Hello xml2js!",
        "$": {
          "id": "sd"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}` How can I get reference to CDATA I need via id? I have tried `results.sd`, `results.roots.root.sd` but none of these work.

Comment: Well, those can't work because as you can see, the object doesn't have a property `sd`. One solution would be to simply iterate over all children and create a new object that maps the id to the content.

Comment: Thanks Felix. Would be great if you could include above comments in an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there is an XML parser that creates `id -> element` mappings, but `xml2js` surely works with CDATA sections and you can easily create such a mapping yourself, assuming your structure is as simple as in the question:

```
var parseString = require('xml2js').parseString;

parseString(xml, function (err, result) {
  var queries = result['sql-requests']['sql-request'].reduce(queries, query) {
      queries[query.$.id] = query._;
      return queries;
  }, {});
  // queries is not an id -> content map
});
```

Comment: Thanks once again Felix!

Comment: You're welcome! Give it a try, I might have made a mistake somewhere but will update if you let me know. I hope the idea is clear though.

Answer (score 1):

```
var parseString = require('xml2js').parseString;
var xml = '<sql-requests>' +
'<sql-request id="insert_product"><![CDATA[INSERT INTO products]]></sql-request>' +
'<sql-request id="insert_account"><![CDATA[INSERT INTO accounts]]></sql-request>' +
'<sql-request id="insert_news"><![CDATA[INSERT INTO news]]></sql-request>' +
'</sql-requests>';

// Prints: '"INSERT INTO products"'
parseString(xml, function (err, result) {
  console.dir(JSON.stringify(result['sql-requests']['sql-request'][0]._));
});
```

Comment: Examples are good but explanations are better. This does not address the issue that the OP wants an `id -> content` mapping at all. Right now your answer is just what I said in the comments expressed as code.